# hadoop-aws - s3a upload limit bandwidth?

Tags: java, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload from IDC to AWS S3 using spark + hadoop-aws.

Because our server in IDC has limited bandwidth and it is shared with our production webserver, I want to limit(throttle down) bandwidth uploading.

How can I limit upload bandwidth with hadoop-aws?

Comment: In aws-cli, s3 support max_bandwidth but is there similar thing in  aws-sdk-java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using distcp you can set the max bandwidth for each worker, set the max #of workers and the peak bandwidth falls out of that.

If FWIW, this is my [CloudCP](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala) app; example of doing this in Spark. I think to throttle that you'd need to limit the upload rate of every file, plus possibly do some global throttling, which would be a fairly complex bit of work: you'd need every worker doing the upload to throttle, get back time and bandwidth of every upload, and use that to tune the next.

First starting point would be a bandwidth throttling version of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy()` to limit the upload rate; manage that and the #of workers and you'd be somewhat in control.

Comment: BTW, Google Guava rate limiter could be used within a single process, but it's "non-obvious" how you could use this across an entire spark cluster. You could do it per-spark-worker so that all uploads sent to that worker were throttled based on the previous uploads' B/W http://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter